# python integral calculation without using for loop

Tags: python

I want to implement a python program, which can calculate this integral
[image: Here is the integral]

I know how to make it using For Loop and it will look something like this

```
import numpy as np;


def numint(f,alpha,beta,N,b,c):
    s = np.size(b);
    x = np.linspace(alpha,beta,N);
    h = x[1]-x[0];
    result = 0;
    result1 = 0;
    for j in range(1,N+1):
        for i in range(1,s+1):
           result1+=b[i]*f(x[j-1]+h*c[i]);
        result+=h*result1;
        result1 = 0;
    return result;
```

Without loop I think it should be something like this:

```
def numint(f,alpha,beta,N,b,c):
    s = np.size(b);
    x = np.linspace(alpha,beta,N);
    h = np.ones(N,dtype=int)*(x[1] - x[0]);
    result = 0;
    result = np.sum(h[1:N+1] * np.sum(b*(f(x[0:N]+h[0]*c))));
    return result;
```

But the second part of the result = np.sum ... is wrong and I dont know how to fix it . Any suggestions ?

EDIT :

```
def numint(f,alpha,beta,N,b,c):
    s = np.size(b);
    x = np.linspace(alpha,beta,N);
    h = np.ones(N,dtype=int)*(x[1] - x[0]);
    functionResult = f(x+h*c);
    dif = np.diff(functionResult);  
    result = 0;
    result = np.sum(h[1:N+1] * np.sum(b*dif.sum()));
    return result;
```

As a tip : vectorize them
but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the np.diff function.

Say you are looking for the integral from 0 to 10 for f(x) = x^2 with F(x) = (x^3)/3:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
F = lambda x: x**3/3
b = F(x)

dif = np.diff(b)

sum = dif.sum()

print(sum)
333.33333333333326
```

Actual result is 333.3...

You can replace F by any function you want, but the key is np.diff which decreases the size of your array by one. Then, just sum the differences along your interval and you have your result.

You can improve the precision of your result by simply increasing the number of steps (1000 in my example).

Comment: Oh , sorry but I'm not sure how  exactly to use this in my code. My function should calculate the quadrature formula for the numerical integration . Can you show me how to use this diff function .

Comment: b = f(x+h*c)
dif = np.diff(b);
and then use this one ?

Comment: Can you tell me if my edit is that what you showed me ?

Comment: I am not quite sure, whether you actually got the function right that calculates the integral. Do you have any reference where you got the equation from, meaning the Latex equation.